# When getting a signed document through the API, there is no signature when I download it

Tags: c#, docusignapi

**Context of my issue**

I am referencing a DocuSign example on how to download an already signed document (https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/get-an-envelope-document-list)

**The code I'm working with**

1. List envelope documents

```
EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
EnvelopeDocumentsResult docsList = envelopesApi.ListDocuments(accountId, envelopeId);

// print the JSON response
Console.WriteLine("EnvelopeDocumentsResult:\n{0}", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(docsList));
```

2. Download the document(s)

```
// instantiate a new EnvelopesApi object
EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
String filePath = String.Empty;
FileStream fs = null;

for (int i = 0; i < docsList.EnvelopeDocuments.Count; i++ ) 
{
    // GetDocument() API call returns a MemoryStream
    MemoryStream docStream = (MemoryStream)envelopesApi.GetDocument(accountId, docsList.EnvelopeId, docsList.EnvelopeDocuments[i].DocumentId);
    // let's save the document to local file system
    filePath = Path.GetTempPath() + Path.GetRandomFileName() + ".pdf";
    fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
    docStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    docStream.CopyTo(fs);
    fs.Close();
    Console.WriteLine("Envelope Document {0} has been downloaded to:  {1}", i, filePath);
}
```

**The issue I'm running into**

I am able to successfully execute the code and download the PDFs to local storage. However, the "signed" document has no signature on it. In the confirmation email that goes out to the signer, the signed document is present. When I make the call via the code above, I get only the original document with no signature.

**My question**

Is there something I'm doing in my code to prevent me from getting the signed copy of the PDF, or do I need to approach this a different way?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the optional argument at the end like this:

```
// produce a ZIP file with all documents including the CoC
Stream results1 = envelopesApi.GetDocument(accountId, envelopeId, "archive");
// produce a PDF combining all signed documents as well as the CoC
Stream results2 = envelopesApi.GetDocument(accountId, envelopeId, "combined");
```

(this code is taken from the [blog post on this topic](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-common-api-tasks-downloading-documents/))

Comment: Hi Inbar. Thank you for your answer. I see now that as I was iterating through the documents in the EnvelopeID, my DocumentID in my code was not necessarily lining up with the DocumentID that DocuSign had on their end. That blog article was very helping in figuring out a better way to pull the documents I need. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help!!

Comment: Hi Inbar. One more question, if you don't mind. After implementing your suggestion (which worked great, by the way), I realized that the real issue I was having was this: My code requests a signature via embedded signing, and I store the EnvelopeID and the URL for later, I then navigate to the URL and sign the document, and return to my app, where I then download the signed documents via the stored EnvelopeID. This is the problem. The EnvelopeID I capture turns out to be different from the EnvelopeID of the signed document. I can't figure out why I'm ended up with 2 different EnvelopeIDs.

Comment: Justin, I'm not sure I understand this issue. Seems like maybe it's not related to DocuSign directly? but to the way you store things in your app? not sure. I would suggest posting a new question about this and including your code snippet if possible (not just for getting the documents from DocuSign, but for how you store/retrieve envelpeIDs)

Comment: Sounds good. I'll do some more digging in my code and make sure it's post a new question if I still can't figure out. Thanks again for your help.